# Pytorch: how to change requires_grad to be true in an OrderedDict

Tags: pytorch, ordereddict

Suppose I have a neural network object from `torch.nn`, by default the `requires_grad` is `False` for its parameters. I want to change it to be `True`. But the following naive approach fails:

```
From torch import nn
a = nn.Linear(1, 1)
a.state_dict()[‘weight’].requires_grad = True
print(a.state_dict()[‘weight’].requires_grad)
```

The result is `False`. Could anyone explain what the problem is and how to fix it? Thank you! My torch version is 1.7.1.

Answer (score 3):

By default **trainable** `nn` objects **parameters** will have `requires_grad=True`.
You can verify that by doing:

```
import torch.nn as nn

layer = nn.Linear(1, 1)

for param in layer.parameters():
    print(param.requires_grad)

# or use
print(layer.weight.requires_grad)
print(layer.bias.requires_grad)
```

To change `requires_grad` state:

```
for param in layer.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False # or True
```